# Postgres Restore

Tags: postgresql, permissions, restore

I need to restore a single schema from production postgres to test.

Test database and schema already exists.

The users/roles & sequences are different on prod to test and after schema is restored in test,  will need to readjust the users/roles & sequences to what it was originally in test.

Can some one help provide steps & commands on how to perform this task?

dump command as follows:

```
pg_dump -h hostname -p port -U pgadmin -n schema1 -d db1 > backupfile_20190715.sql -v
```

Not sure how I restore the test schema. Do I drop schema1 first in test and run the script in? How about user/roles. How do I put back what was there in test after restoring from production backup.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom format `pg_dump` with the `-Fc` option.

Don't restore permissions and ownership by using the `-x` and `-O` options of `pg_restore`. You will then have to write and apply an SQL script that adjusts the ownership and permissions.

There is no need to change the sequences.